# i18next - strings don't update when the language is changed

Tags: angularjs, localization, i18next

I am integrating the i18next library with my Angular 1.5.3 project.

https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next

When I use the changeLanguage feature the strings on my page don't update to the correct language.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/8.4.1/i18next.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-i18next/1.0.4/ng-i18next.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      Hello, {{name}}!
      <div ng-i18next="HELLO"></div>
      <button ng-click="change()">change lng</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my app.js

```
if (window.i18next) {
  window.i18next.init({
    debug: true,
    lng: 'en', // If not given, i18n will detect the browser language.
    fallbackLng: 'en', // Default is dev
    resources: {},
    useCookie: false,
    useLocalStorage: false,
    joinArrays: '<br />'
  });
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'jm.i18next']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope, $i18next) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';

  $scope.change = function() {
    $i18next.i18n.changeLanguage('fr', function(err, t) {
      console.log(t('HELLO')); //prints out bonjour
    });
    console.log($i18next.t('HELLO')); //prints out hiya
  };

  $i18next.i18n.addResourceBundle('en', 'translation', {
    'HELLO': 'hiya'
  });

  $i18next.i18n.addResourceBundle('fr', 'translation', {
    'HELLO': 'bonjour'
  });

  console.log($i18next.t('HELLO')); //prints out hiya
}
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7oI13bNJVqVgTEFOT6bk

I don't know how I can 'refresh' my page to get the correct translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sLb2CA7hPtK00SYo7M1m?p=preview)**

Use this to change the language `$i18next.changeLanguage('fr');`

Replace:

```
$i18next.i18n.changeLanguage('fr', function(err, t) {
  console.log(t('HELLO')); //prints out bonjour
});
```

with this:

`$i18next.changeLanguage('fr');`

**Translations in the controller**
For translations to be performed in the controller after a language change happens, listen for the `i18nextLanguageChange` event and then perform translations like below.

```
  // Listen for the language change event and perform $scope bindings
  $scope.$on('i18nextLanguageChange', function () {
    // Inside a timeout to allow the language change to complete
    $timeout(function () {
      console.log($i18next.t('HELLO'));}
      );
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the page reloading? Can we force angular to re-render the page?

Comment: @user1261710 Found a way to get i18next directives to work without page reloads. You need to publish an event in the callback handler. I've updated my answer.

Comment: wow great job it works! How about any translatins attached to $scope? for example, $scope.hello = $i18next.t('HELLO')

Comment: Actually, there is a simpler fix. See my updated answer for the recommended way of changing the language. This way, you do not need to broadcast any events. The i18next framework will take care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks that also worked out. It changed the directive ones but not the scope one I did.

Comment: @user1261710 I've updated my answer to reflect scope translation as well